# Trying to import a android project into Android studio error

Tags: java, android

I am new to android studio and tried to import a project which someone else had made into it .The project has google play services jar file in its libs folder.I got the following error while importing:

Why does this error occour and how do i fix it?Will it be shown for other library files also?

Comment: is your project lib folder contain google play service lib ?

Comment: @Achuthan M..hey its better to hide project specifics(like name etc ) when you post the question... സ്വാമിയെ ശരണമയ്യപ്പാ!

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when your external library or the dependencies are not added in the Android Studio Properly .

So what you can do is :

1.Put the jar file into the libs folder.

2.Right click it and hit 'Add as library'.

3.Ensure that compile files('libs/google-play-services_lib.jar') is in your build.gradle file and Finally add the dependencies.

Eg.

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: '../jar', include: '*.jar')

    compile project(':pull-to-refresh')

    compile files('libraries/abcdef.jar')

    compile files('libraries/google-play-services_lib.jar')

}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

With Gooole Play Services - you don't have to even copy library from old project to new one. You can get it is easily by adding in build.gradle in dependecies section:

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'

(or any other version, that will be suitable for you) and lib will be automatically downloaded/added